# How to set serial port on my machine?

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to use minicom to check serial connection but I'm not able to. Running `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS0` gave the following result:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

I have tried most of the things suggested out there but nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the settings in minicom by pressing CTRL+A and then Z?

Comment: what exactly should I change in the settings? Actually, minicom is able to show results in another laptop with similar settings as mine. The only difference being with  'sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS0' command,
 UART has a number assigned whereas mine is unknown.

Comment: What does `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS1` return? Do any of the ttyS* devices return anything? On my machine, ttys0 returns a UART port type, but the rest return "unknown".

Comment: No, all are Unknown on my machine

Comment: Also, running `sudo minicom -s` (edit configuration file) or `C-a, z, o` (select within minicom session) will allow you to specify which port minicom will use.

Comment: Can you please edit the output of the following command into your question: `dmesg | grep tty`?

Comment: The command you mentioned gave me a bunch of results, one of them being 'console [ttyS0] enabled'. If this is what you asked for.  Also i would like to add that I tried this 'sudo setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A'. This would set the port UART port type but on reboot it becomes unknown again.

Comment: After you set the type using `/dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A`, but before you rebooted (and undid the change), did the port function as you wanted? Additionally, could you be more specific about the results you expect vs. what you are seeing? What is your setup?

Comment: No, the results are not seen after setting the type either. I am trying to check the serial connection on my stm nucleo board. I have connected the tx and rx pin and the code sends some characters which the rx receives. I'm using minicom to check this. The code, connection and minicom all work fine on another laptop but not on mine.

Comment: What kind of device is on the other end of this serial connection? You do mean a DB9, RS232 type serial connection, right?

Comment: I am trying to create a loopback on my ARM stm nucleo board by connecting the uart tx and rx pins. https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F401RE/ .